# AWS Cognito/React.js newPasswordRequired Challenge

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a login flow for my web app built in React and I'm using AWS Cognito for user management. I'm working on the login flow, and I have a use case where a user is created via the AWS Console and a temporary password is provided to the user. When the user goes to login to my application for the first time, AWS Cognito returns a newPasswordRequired Challenge, and the user is forced to change their password.

I'm using the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` API to authenticate the user. The docs for that can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-admin-created-user.html). I have the `newPasswordRequired` callback function setup just like the docs instruct, but I'm struggling to figure out the best way to gather the new password from the user using React within the `newPasswordRequired`function. I initially used `prompt()` within the function to get the inputs, but I would like the app to flow to a new page where the user can enter a new password, confirm new password, and login to the app. That new page should be able to call the `cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge()` that is required to update the new password. Please HELP! Here's my code below:

```
onFormSubmission = (username, password) => {
    const poolData = {
      UserPoolId : AWSConfig.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
      ClientId : AWSConfig.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
    }
    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool
    }
    const authenticationData = {
        Username : username,
        Password : password
    }
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
          console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
          /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
          console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
     },
     newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
          // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
          // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
          // authentication.

          // userAttributes: object, which is the user's current profile. It will list all attributes that are associated with the user.
          // Required attributes according to schema, which don’t have any values yet, will have blank values.
          // requiredAttributes: list of attributes that must be set by the user along with new password to complete the sign-in.

*** THIS IS WHERE I WANT REACT TO RENDER A NEW PAGE TO GET THE NEW PASSWORD***

          // Get these details and call
          // newPassword: password that user has given
          // attributesData: object with key as attribute name and value that the user has given.
          cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(pw, userAttributes, this);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginScreenComponent isInvalidForm={this.state.isInvalidForm} onFormSubmission={this.onFormSubmission}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem! Here is my solution:

`Login.js` react container can render two different components. `<NewPassswordForm />` is to ask a new password, `<LoginForm />` is for common login. According to `isFirstLogin` flag you decide which one to render.

Since you have the cognito user in `this.state.user` you can use it to call `completeNewPasswordChallenge` to finish the login flow:

```
handleLogin = (username, password) => {
  const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
  });
  const userData = {
    Username: username,
    Pool: getUserPool(),
    Storage: getStorage(),
  };
  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      // login
    }
    newPasswordRequired: userAttr => {
      this.setState({
        isFirstLogin: true,
        user: cognitoUser,
        userAttr: userAttr,
      });
    },
  });
};

changePassword = (newPassword) => {
  const cognitoUser = this.state.user;
  const userAttr = this.state.userAttr;
  cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttr, {
    onSuccess: result => {
      // login
    }
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.isFirstLogin ? (
        <NewPassswordForm changePassword={this.changePassword} />
      ) : (
        <LoginForm handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just the answer I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem!! ;)

Comment: I'm receiving `{code: "UnknownError", message: "Unknown error"}` response from Cognito after using the method you mentioned above. Did you have this issue at all as well?

Comment: I changed the code. Check it out .. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51105278/revisions

Comment: For some reason, I'm still receiving the Unknown Error. Reference this questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268933/aws-cognito-completenewpasswordchallenge-calls-onfailure-method-but-the-user-is

Comment: @froston, can you point me out what is the `Storage` option in the `userData`, please?

Comment: @froston, Is this smth like local or session storage so the user data will be saved there?

Comment: @Art713 Storage is optional here. By default cognito will store the tokens in `localStorage`. With this option you can change it to `sessionStorage`, cookies or your custom storage.